# Is it possible that information_schema.columns doesn't hold an user table column information?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, aurora

I am facing a strange issue here. I have a table which is not visible in `information_schema.columns` view. What could be the reason for that.

Note: I am using RDS Aurora Postgresql 9.6.12

Comment: Could you please show the table definition you expect and how you query `information_schema.columns`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, you are correct. That specific table owner was different, my bad.

Comment: @dezso, I was trying to compare two schema (tables and columns and datatypes)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think you should combine your two comments into an actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only see entries for a table in the `information_schema` views if you have permissions on the table in question.

You can get column metadata for tables where you have no access from `pg_attribute`, but you have to deal with PostgreSQL's internal data structures that may change between versions.